# Adminer not working - Configuration file is missing

Tags: linux, debian, apache2, debian-squeeze

I have a VM running Debian 9.7.0 64-bit off a Windows 10 host machine. This VM has the packages `openssh-server`, `ufw`, `mysql-server`, `mysql-client`, `adminer`, and their dependencies installed via `apt`.

Mysql and Apache both appear to be functioning - I can connect to the mysql server over LAN, and the apache2 default webpage appears when accessing the server on port 80. However, trying to access adminer using the `/adminer` or `/adminer.php` url presents a 404 not found error:

```
The requested URL /adminer was not found on this server.
```

Researching this issue brought me to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813282/how-to-configure-adminer-to-be-reachable-on-the-local-network

However, the fix proposed isn't possible for me - The `/etc/adminer` directory is empty. There's no config file to edit, symlink, or otherwise make use of:

```
sierradmin@mysqldev:~$ ls -al /etc/adminer
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 20  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 79 root root 4096 Jan 27 13:59 ..
sierradmin@mysqldev:~$
```

What steps can I take to fix adminer and get it functioning over lan?

I have tried reinstalling adminer and apache, reinstalling the entire server, and installing apache2 first then adminer in separate steps with no success.

EDIT1:
Here's the results of running `dpkg --listfiles adminer`. There doesn't seem to be any config files listed here.

```
sierradmin@mysqldev:~$ dpkg --listfiles adminer
/.
/etc
/etc/adminer
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/adminer
/usr/share/adminer/adminer
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/call.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/create.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/database.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/db.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/download.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/elastic.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/firebird.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/mongo.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/mssql.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/mysql.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/oracle.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/pgsql.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/simpledb.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/drivers/sqlite.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/dump.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/edit.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/event.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/file.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/foreign.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/adminer.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/auth.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/bootstrap.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/connect.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/coverage.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/design.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/driver.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/editing.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/functions.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/lang.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/pdo.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/tmpfile.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/version.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/include/xxtea.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/index.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/indexes.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ar.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/bg.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/bn.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/bs.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ca.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/cs.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/da.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/de.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/el.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/en.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/es.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/et.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/fa.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/fi.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/fr.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/gl.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/hu.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/id.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/it.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ja.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ko.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/lt.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/nl.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/no.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/pl.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/pt-br.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/pt.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ro.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ru.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/sk.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/sl.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/sr.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/ta.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/th.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/tr.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/uk.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/vi.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/xx.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/zh-tw.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/lang/zh.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/plugin.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/privileges.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/procedure.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/processlist.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/schema.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/scheme.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/script.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/select.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/sequence.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/sql.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/arrow.gif
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/cross.gif
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/default.css
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/down.gif
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/editing.js
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/favicon.ico
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/functions.js
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/plus.gif
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/static/up.gif
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/table.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/trigger.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/type.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/user.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/variables.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/adminer/view.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/compile.php
/usr/share/adminer/coverage.php
/usr/share/adminer/designs
/usr/share/adminer/designs/brade
/usr/share/adminer/designs/brade/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/bueltge
/usr/share/adminer/designs/bueltge/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/cvicebni-ubor
/usr/share/adminer/designs/cvicebni-ubor/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/galkaev
/usr/share/adminer/designs/galkaev/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/haeckel
/usr/share/adminer/designs/haeckel/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/hever
/usr/share/adminer/designs/hever/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/jukin
/usr/share/adminer/designs/jukin/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/kahi
/usr/share/adminer/designs/kahi/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/konya
/usr/share/adminer/designs/konya/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/nette
/usr/share/adminer/designs/nette/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/ng9
/usr/share/adminer/designs/ng9/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/nicu
/usr/share/adminer/designs/nicu/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pappu687
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pappu687/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/paranoiq
/usr/share/adminer/designs/paranoiq/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pepa-linha
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pepa-linha/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pilot
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pilot/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pokorny
/usr/share/adminer/designs/pokorny/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/price
/usr/share/adminer/designs/price/adminer.css
/usr/share/adminer/designs/readme.txt
/usr/share/adminer/editor
/usr/share/adminer/editor/db.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/example.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/include
/usr/share/adminer/editor/include/adminer.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/include/connect.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/include/editing.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/index.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/script.inc.php
/usr/share/adminer/editor/static
/usr/share/adminer/editor/static/editing.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals
/usr/share/adminer/externals/JsShrink
/usr/share/adminer/externals/JsShrink/jsShrink.php
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/jush.css
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-cnf.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-css.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-htm.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-http.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-js.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-mssql.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-oracle.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-pgsql.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-php.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-simpledb.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-sql.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-sqlite.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-textarea.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush-txt.js
/usr/share/adminer/externals/jush/modules/jush.js
/usr/share/adminer/lang.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/database-hide.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-alter.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-bz2.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-date.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-json.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-php.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-xml.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/dump-zip.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/edit-calendar.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/edit-foreign.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/edit-textarea.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/email-table.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/enum-option.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/file-upload.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/foreign-system.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/frames.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/json-column.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/links-direct.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/login-servers.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/login-table.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/master-slave.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/plugin.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/readme.txt
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/slugify.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/sql-log.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/tables-filter.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/tinymce.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/translation.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/version-noverify.php
/usr/share/adminer/plugins/wymeditor.php
/usr/share/adminer/tests
/usr/share/adminer/tests/0-login.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/1-create-database.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/10-clone.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/11-reference.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/12-update.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/13-delete.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/14-truncate.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/15-privileges.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/16-processlist.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/17-export.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/18-events.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/19-procedures.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/2-create-table.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/20-partitioning.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/21-variables.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/22-history.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/23-editor.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/24-explain.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/3-create-index.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/4-create-table-2.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/5-foreign-key.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/6-alter-table.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/7-create-trigger.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/8-create-view.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/9-insert.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/iexplore.bat
/usr/share/adminer/tests/logout.html
/usr/share/adminer/tests/selenium.html
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/adminer
/usr/share/doc/adminer/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/adminer/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/adminer/copyright
/usr/share/doc/adminer/readme.txt
/usr/share/doc/adminer/todo.txt
sierradmin@mysqldev:~$
```

Comment: `dpkg --listfiles adminer` should list which configuration and other files are installed and where.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, work got busy this week - I've run this and copied the output into the original question. It doesn't look like any config files are included.